# Polymer core-list not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer, web-component, polymer-designer-tool

We have a Polymer page in an application using core-list component. The component works perfectly fine with Firefox and Safari. However with Chrome it behaves weird. Any Polymer expert who can help solve this issue ? Here are details of the issue:

**Code:**

```
    <core-list id="dashboardList" data="{{dashboard_list}}" on-core-activate="{{editDashboardTapped}}" height="100" selectionEnabled layout horizontal flex>
    <template>
        <div class="row {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList}}" layout horizontal center>
            <div><paper-checkbox checked="{{model.checked}}"></paper-checkbox></div>
            <div flex two>{{model.title}}</div>
            <div flex two>{{model.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</core-list>
```

**Issue:** 
In Firefox/Safari, row click works fine and "on-core-activate" function (editDashboardTapped) is called correctly. However in Chrome, the function is not called.

I am using latest version of Chrome (43.0.2357.81)

Appreciate any pointer in correct direction.

Comment: Anyone faced this issue earlier ??

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. My core-list did work in Firefox and not in Chrome. I noticed that Chrome gave me an error that no height was set, even though I set height to 100%.

Changing height:100% to height:500px fixed it. Not an ideal solution, but hopefully it will help you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we were using Polymer version 0.5 (yeah not sure who decided to do that), but an upgrade to production version 1.0 resolved the issue.